# Linux gs - not working as expected

Tags: pdf

I'm running the following command to create a PDF out of a string of images (JPG+PNG):

```
convert -adjoin * "presentation.pdf" ; gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -sOutputFile=the_presentation.pdf presentation.pdf
```

While presentation.pdf is created, the_presentation.pdf is not.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot -sDEVICE=pdfwrite . Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: I can only do that in two days for some reason